# What is the meaning when someone say "it doesn't get much weird than Lynda?"

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, idioms, meaning-in-context

Lynda made a dance performance, it's very weird and many audiences couldn't understand it. Then a guy made a comment "It doesn't get much weird than Lynda?". What does he mean ?

Is that "Lynda is very weird, that why her performance would be weird too"?

Comment: It doesn’t get much *weird**er*** than...

Comment: Evidently the guy mistyped his comment about weird Lynda... or my ears misread it. It smells funny to me, too.

Comment: *It* here is similar to the dummy pronoun in *it's raining*, and means something like *the general condition*. So he's saying *nothing gets weirder than Lydia [that weird, weird dancer, does]*. In other words, *Lydia is the weirdest, amirite*?

Comment: The guy is trying to say that nothing would be more weird than Lynda's performance.